# Framework para ler json google maps api

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Queria saber se existe algum framework para ler os dados que vem no json do google maps directions? tipo, pegue os dados e coloque em variáveis que eu posso pegar e usar no resto da aplicação

Comment: Gson. Coloca no Google.

Comment: Pode mostrar um exemplo de uso?

Comment: @Costamilam, vc terá que criar uma classe para representar cada item do json que mostrou ao Venturelli. Uma classe `GeocodedWaipoint`, uma classe `Route`, uma classe `Bound`, uma `Leg`, e muitas mais. Cada atributo que contenha atributos internos precisará ser uma classe. Com isso é necessário seguir os passos descritos pelo próprio Venturelli.

Comment: Parece que encontrei algo pra [facilitar a vida de todo mundo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/). É só colar o JSON, modificar as opções e apertar Preview.

Comment: Verdade @Gustavo Cinque, esqueci que existia esse gerador de classes, obrigado pela ajuda, coloque numa reposta e aceito a tua resposta, o problema é que agora eu já criei as 23 classes mas da próxima vou tentar lembrar

Comment: Pode aceitar a do @IgorVenturelli mesmo amigo, eu peço pra ele incluir na resposta debaixo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode usar o [Google Gson](https://github.com/google/gson).

Com ele, você define uma classe e ele popula todos os atributos para você. Por exemplo:

```
public class Pessoa {

    private String nome;
    private int idade;

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public int getIdade() {
        return idade;
    }

    public void setIdade(int idade) {
        this.idade = idade;
    }
}
```

---

Considerando o JSON:

```
{  
   "nome":"Joao",
   "idade":"25"
}
```

Então você pode fazer:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Pessoa pessoaDoJson = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Pessoa.class);
```

E o Gson vai transferir os valores do JSON para os atributos do objeto `pessoaDoJson`.

Se quiser, você pode fazer o caminho inverso também: dado um objeto populado, criar um JSON:

```
Pessoa p = new Pessoa();
p.setNome("Joao");
p.setIdade(25);

String json = gson.toJson(p);

//o valor da variável json é: { "nome":"Joao", "idade":"25" }
```

---

**EDIT:**

Para facilitar, você pode usar algo como o [jsonSchema2Pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) para montar seu POJO baseado no JSON.

Comment: [Olha minha situação.](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/9WuE3PilftU/maxresdefault.jpg)

Comment: Mas boa amigo, Gson resolve mesmo. Ou então tente Jackson. Outro framework com o mesmo resultado.

Comment: [o problema é que o json do google maps é gigante](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?&mode=transit&alternatives=true&origin=-30.0096831,-51.1564772&destination=-30.041941572853005,-51.164713092148304)

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam não consigo ver o JSON.. Dá erro de acesso.. Gigante em qual sentido? Muitos atributos ou atributos muito grandes?

Comment: gigante nos dois sentidos, são vários array de objetos com outros objetos e arrays de objeto, se eu fosse fazer todas as classes daria mais de 20 com certeza

Comment: Precisa ter controle direto do JSON? Se não você pode usar [essa biblioteca](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-java). `DirectionsResult result = DirectionsApi.getDirections(sc.context, "Sydney, AU", "Melbourne, AU").await();` já te dá os resultados com POJOS.

Comment: pode reformular a resposta com um exemplo de uso, de preferencia com o `&mode=transit`?

Comment: @IgorVenturelli, adicione o criador de classes por JSON que eu coloquei como comentário da pergunta na sua resposta, pode ser?

Comment: @GustavoCinque vc diz o jsonschma2pojo? É pra eu adicionar na resposta?

Comment: Sim. Esse mesmo.

Comment: @GustavoCinque beleza já já altero a resposta

Comment: @GustavoCinque resposta editada ;)