# Java e JSON API

Tags: java, json, api

Gostaria de saber se alguém conhece uma API boa e com tutoriais para criar, editar, escrever e ler arquivos JSON em Java.

Estou pesquisando há algum tempo e até agora não encontrei.

Comment: `FileStreamReader`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu, particularmente, gosto bastante da lib [Google GSON](https://github.com/google/gson).

Com ela você pode, a partir de uma classe Java, montar seu JSON e vice-e-versa.

No próprio repositório do projeto (link acima) tem um mini tutorial de como usar. É bem simples.

Todavia, [essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/254325/5963) também mostra como usar a lib.

---

Caso queira mexer no JSON "na unha", você pode usar a API nativa do Java: [`javax.json`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/package-summary.html)